# Problems with layout in XML

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have tried to follow a tutorial om how to create a Viewflipper in android. Everything seems to work, the only this is that I want the layout differently. At the moment it contains 3 buttons and a webview, The 3 buttons located at the top and the webview below. I would like the buttons to be at the bottom and webview to be above. Please help a beginner in need!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<HorizontalScrollView
 android:id="@+id/main_horizontal_container"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_access_profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_blank_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_access_profile"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_access_portfolio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_blank_1"
            android:text="Portfolio"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_blank_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_access_portfolio"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_access_history"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_blank_2"
            android:text="History"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/main_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/main_horizontal_container" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_test1"
        layout="@layout/test1" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_test2"
        layout="@layout/test2" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_test3"
        layout="@layout/test3" />
</ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the test1.xml File containing the WebView!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/test1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="421dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the example uses a RelativeLayout you have to change the attributes wich define the positioning.
In your file it will be the line

```
android:layout_below="@id/main_horizontal_container"
```

in the ViewFlipper.

Change

```
android:layout_below
```

to

```
android:layout_above
```

Comment: The whole webview disappeared when using that and no change in position of the buttons. It seems like the buttons are "stuck" at the top?